# prove that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = 0 \forall c \in [0,1] $

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question in real analysis that states: 
if $A_n$ a finite subset of $[0,1]$ and $A_n \cap A_m = \phi $ if $n \neq m$
and a function is defined byL

$$ f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{n} & x\in A_n \\
      0 &  x\notin \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$
   \end{cases}
$$
I want to show that:
if $c \in [0,1]$ then
$$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = 0 $$

my process, I've tried to consider a sequence $x_m \notin A_n$ such that $x_m \to c$ but that didn't get me anywhere

Comment: You need to pick an **arbitrary** sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $[0,1]$ that converges to $c$ and prove/disprove $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0$. As a hint distinguish two cases. (1) There exists an $n$ s.t. $c\in A_n$. (2) There does not exist such an $n$.

Comment: @DavidKraemer wait does that mean it converges to 1?

Comment: @Toni I'll try to do that

Comment: @Linom Nevermind, when we consider sequential characterization of limits we only allow sequences $x_n \ne c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, suppose that $x_n \to c$ for a sequence entirely outside of $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. Then $f(x_n) \equiv 0$ for all $n$, and so $f(x_n) \to 0$.

Now, let $x_n \to c$ for a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ contained in $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$, and let $\varepsilon > 0$. 
Fix $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $N^{-1} < \varepsilon$. 
The set $B_N = \bigcup_{n=1}^{N} A_n$ is finite, so we can fix $\delta > 0$ such that

$$
0 < \delta < \min \{|y-c| : y \ne c, y \in B_N \}.
$$
Since $x_n \to c$, we can fix $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|c - x_n| < \delta$ for all $n \geq M$. Suppose $n \geq \max(M, N)$. Then $x_n \notin B_N$, which means that $f(x_n) = n^{-1} < N^{-1} < \varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon> 0$ was arbitrary, $f(x_n) \to 0$.

---

An arbitrary sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $[0,1]$ may be partitioned into two subsequences: the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ lying in $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ and the subsequence $(x_{n_\ell})$ lying outside. From the above, we have $f(x_{n_k}) \to 0$ and $f(x_{n_\ell}) \to 0$, so we can conclude that $f(x_n) \to 0$.

**Edit**. Got momentarily confused about the sequential characterization of limits.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $ \lim _{x \to c} f(x) = 0 $ , we need to show that for any $ \epsilon \gt 0 $ there is a $ \delta \gt 0$ such that $ \lvert f(x) - 0 \rvert \lt \epsilon $ as long as $ x \not = c $ and $ \lvert x - c \rvert \lt \delta $. Therefore, we need to show that for any $ \epsilon \gt 0 $ there is a $ \delta \gt 0$ such that $ \lvert f(x) \rvert \lt \epsilon $ as long as $ x \not = c $ and $ \lvert x - c \rvert \lt \delta $.

Select a finite integer $k$ such that $ k \gt \frac 1 \epsilon $. Let the set $ S = \bigcup _{n=-k} ^{n=k} A _{n}$ , and the set $ S^{*} = \{ \lvert x - c \rvert : x \in S \setminus \{ c \} \}$. Since both $ k $ and all $ A _{n} $ is finite, $ S $ is finite, and $ S ^{*} $ is therefore also finite. Let $ \delta = \inf S ^{*} $ and we know that $ \delta \gt 0 $ .

Now we will show that if $ x \not = c $ and $ \lvert x - c \rvert \lt \delta $ , $ f(x) \lt \epsilon $ . Since $ \delta = \inf S ^{*} $ , $ x \not = c $ and $ \lvert x - c \rvert \lt \delta $ , $ x \not \in S $ . Therefore $ f(x) = 0 $ or $ f(x) = \frac 1 n $ for some integer $ n $ such that $ \lvert n \rvert \gt k $ . If $ f(x) = 0 $ , we are done. Otherwise, since $ \lvert n \rvert \gt k $ , $ \lvert \frac 1 n \rvert \lt \frac 1 k $ . Since $ k \gt \frac 1 \epsilon $ , $ \frac 1 k \lt \epsilon $ . Therefore $ f(x) \lt \epsilon $ . $ \square $